# Layout misplacement when scaling absolute positioned and em sized element in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am creating an arrow shape which can scale according to the parent container font size. So I use the `em` unit for scalability.

When I try to scale the arrow using Chrome builtin zoom features, or give different `font-size` to the `.container`, sometimes the arrow has layout misplacement as illustrated below (Notice the little gap between the arrow and stroke)

Normal [image]
Zoom: 110% [image]

I have tried with different arrow patterns (sizes, directions), and similar issue occurs occasionally in different zoom ratios in both Chrome and Firefox. The code I used for the above image is as follow:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            position: relative;
            margin: 3em;
        }
        .arrow-left {
            position: absolute; 
            top: 0; 
            left: -2em; 
            border: 2em solid transparent; 
            border-right: 2em solid #333; 
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
        }
        .stroke {
            position: absolute;
            top: 1em;
            left: 2em;
            width: 5em;
            height: 2em;
            background-color: #333;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="arrow-left"></div>
        <div class="stroke" style=""></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any guidelines I can follow when using the `em` unit so that scaling would not produce this effect?

Comment: First, you shouldn't worry about your page being pixel-perfect at different zoom levels than 100%. That's the point of `zoom`. You give up on pixel-perfect-ness for either readability or birds-eye-view of content. Secondly, drawing the arrow in one `path` inside a `svg` would clearly solve your problem at any zoom level.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Thanks for your quick reply. Except using the builtin zoom, I also try to give the `.container` different `font-size`, and the same issue occurs at some `font-size`. I think svg is a good solution for shape. But still isn't this a strange behavior as the `em` unit is supposed to scale all the things ubiquitously?

Comment: `em` changes throughout the page depending on font size of current element. If you want to have a general relative unit, use `rem` (root em). It's bound to `em` of `<body>` element. And all your `zoom`s will be proportional in all parts of page, regardless of local `font-size`. I'm not sure this solves your problem though. But it might.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I may have wrong. But from my understanding `rem` and `em` should not affect the question. While rem bound to `em` of `<body>`, In my example both `.arrow-left` and `.stroke` elements they do not have their own font size, so they instead bound to the parent `.container` font size. But the way I find it strange is that given `2em`, they calculate different  values and produce the little gap.

Comment: I've been wondering about the same question

Answer (score 0):

If you move the `arrow point` to cover a little of the `stroke`, you can "solve" the gap problem when zooming.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 3em;
}

.arrow-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -1.9em; /*  */
  border: 2em solid transparent;
  border-right: 2em solid #333;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.stroke {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 2em;
  width: 5em;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow-left"></div>
  <div class="stroke" style=""></div>
</div>
```